# Is there any relation between the meanings of the word "cataract"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, semantics, literary-english

[Oxford](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/cataract?q=cataract) defines "cataract" as "a steep waterfall" as well as gives the more common meaning of the word i.e. the medical condition that causes a loss of sight.

Also, "cataract", as meaning "waterfall", is used in literature. The following is from Wordsworth's *Intimation of Immortality*

> And I again am strong:
>   The cataracts blow their trumpets from the
>   steep

This is an odd pair of meanings being of the same word. Is there is any reason why "cataract" means both "waterfall and "loss of sight"?

Thank you.

Comment: The wikipedia article on the medical condition offers a possible explanation for this: "As rapidly running water turns white, so the term may have been used metaphorically to describe the similar appearance of mature ocular opacities. In Latin, cataracta had the alternative meaning "portcullis" and the name possibly passed through French to form the English meaning "eye disease" (early 15th century), on the notion of "obstruction".

Comment: The effect of the eye disease that in medicine is called cataract is that your sight diminishes as if a veil of water is flowing over your eyes. It is as if you would look through a waterfall. But I must admit I don't understand your quote of Wordsworth.

Comment: In medicine the Greek word cataract (waterfall) is used as a kind of shortened metaphor. The longer form could be "the cataract disease of the eye/eyes".

Answer (score 5):

Actually, this was fairly easy to research.  From **Wikipedia**:

> "Cataract" is derived from the Latin cataracta, meaning "waterfall",
>   and from the Ancient Greek καταρράκτης (katarrhaktēs),
>   "down-rushing",[52] from καταράσσω (katarassō) meaning "to dash
>   down"[53] (from kata-, "down"; arassein, "to strike, dash").[54] As
>   rapidly running water turns white, so the term may have been used
>   metaphorically to describe the similar appearance of mature ocular
>   opacities. In Latin, cataracta had the alternative meaning
>   "portcullis"[55] and the name possibly passed through French to form
>   the English meaning "eye disease" (early 15th century), on the notion
>   of "obstruction".[56] Early Persian physicians called the term
>   nazul-i-ah, or "descent of the water"—vulgarised into waterfall
>   disease or cataract—believing such blindness to be caused by an
>   outpouring of corrupt humour into the eye.[57]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataract

Answer (score 1):

All of the above are true but, to fully answer the question, it's worth mentioning three more archaic usages of cataract:

1. to describe a deluge of rain (I wonder whether both waterfalls and extremely heavy rainfall - especially when cascading from a roof - can feel rather like a Roman portcullis, preventing travel either into or out of a building, or - for river travellers - an unexplored continent?);
2. similarly, to describe a waterspout or geyser - where turbulent swirling water shoots up from underground to drench onlookers (sometimes imagined at the mouths of caves and tunnel systems, these can act with the sudden, daunting unpredictability of an enemy portcullis - deterring venture);
3. lastly, to describe a tempest or whirlwind - especially where raincloud, but sometimes milky-white cloud, gets twisted up in the swirl. This last, ancient, usage is probably the imagery wrapped into Wordsworth's decidedly spiritual quote.

Comment: Could you provide some citations?

Comment: Also, can you address the OP's primary request which is how the word can mean both 'waterfall' and 'loss of sight'?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an English major, but I'd like to add a different spin on the origin of the word.

Cataracta, also known as a portucullis, also references to a defensive gate that ancient civilizations would use a defense. The oldest of the civilizations includes the ancient Jews in the time of King David, the second king of Ancient Israel.

This gate would serve as defense against invaders looking to get into Jerusalem.

So similar to how cataracts is a cloudy lens that blocks our vision. Cataracta is an ancient gate that blocks invaders from getting into Jerusalem.

But being King David, it goes a little deeper. In Psalms 24:7 David shouts at the ancient Gates to open up to allow the "King of Glory" to come in.

So just like how cataracts blocks our ability to see anything...cataracta blocks our ability to see the "King of Glory". Of course we don't use ancient Gates to defend ourselves but David refers to the ancient Gates of our hearts.

Source: https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/secondary/SMIGRA*/Cataracta.html

Comment: *Cataracta* is a Latin word so how does it relate to Jerusalem, where they spoke a variety of languages including Hebrew, Aramaic, and Koine Greek but not really Latin. The source you provide traces the word to Vegetius who was active c. 450 CE, long after the Roman destruction of Jerusalem.